# Contradictory Usage of だろう・でしょう

Tags: word-choice, nuances, particles

I continue seeing sentences that (based on my knowledge) seem to contain conflicting usages of だろう・でしょう.

> 「妻はルイヴィトンのバッグを欲しがっているんだけど、そんなもん、買えるわけないでしょう！ 」

To my understanding わけがない is an expression that denotes absolute certainty, so it seems counterintuitive that it is followed by でしょう (a word that demonstrates a much weaker degree of certainty). My best guess it that でしょう is used here in order to soften the overall tone of the statement.

> 「そうしたらきっと馬鹿にされてしまうのでしょう。」
>   If I did that I would be made fun of.

This one confuses me because it isn't translated as "If I did that I would **probably** be made fun of." The "probably" part is omitted. This is not a unique example, though. I've seen lots of relatively simple sentences including だろうthat end up being translated without using "probably".

I'm sorry that the format of this post is a mess; my thoughts are jumbled and I couldn't figure out a great way to organize it.

So to conclude I guess I'm asking if someone could explain why だろう・でしょう is included in the examples I've given/similar cases. Thank you!

Comment: ～わけないだろう etc. are だろう・でしょう in the 'isn't it?/right?' sense. It's rhetorical here, implying the statement is obvious. It doesn't weaken but strengthen the statement.

Comment: Do you also consider the  English sentence "It might never happen." contradictory?